# System.Linq.Lookup vs. Wintellect.PowerCollections.MultiDictionary

Tags: c#, linq

I still use Wintellect's PowerCollections library, even though it is aging and not maintained because it did a good job covering holes left in the standard MS Collections libraries.  But LINQ and C# 4.0 are poised to replace PowerCollections...

I was very happy to discover System.Linq.Lookup because it should replace `Wintellect.PowerCollections.MultiDictionary` in my toolkit.  But `Lookup` seems to be immutable!  Is that true, can you only created a populated Lookup by calling `ToLookup`?

Comment: Turns out the answer is in MSDN, too: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460184(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can only create a `Lookup` by calling `ToLookup`. The immutable nature of it means that it's easy to share across threads etc, of course.

If you want a mutable version, you could always use the [Edulinq implementation](http://code.google.com/p/edulinq/source/browse/src/Edulinq/Lookup.cs) as a starting point. It's internally mutable, but externally immutable - and I wouldn't be surprised if the Microsoft implementation worked in a similar way.

Personally I'm rarely in a situation where I want to mutate the lookup - I would prefer to perform appropriate transformations on the input first. I would encourage you to think in this way too - I find myself wishing for better immutability support from other collections (e.g. `Dictionary`) more often than I wish that `Lookup` were mutable :)

Comment: `Lookup` is implemented with an array of a nested `internal` `Grouping` class, where each `Grouping` is basically a key/values pair. These groupings are mutable internally. (So yes, your assumption is, as usual, spot on.)

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. `Lookup` is immutable, you can create an instance by using the Linq `ToLookup()` extension method. Technically even that fact is an implementation detail since the method returns an `ILookup` interface which in the future might be implemented by some other concrete class.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'll probably end up writing my own class, and I'll make sure to implement `ILookup<K, V>` as well as `IDictionary<K, IEnumerable<V>>`.